# Custom Control from sealed control in silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight

how to create a Custom Control from sealed control in silverlight 4.0
please help me,
I want to create a control for scrollViewer, but ScrollViewer is a sealed class we can't inherit it.

Answer (score 2):

it's `sealed`. you can not derive a child class from it. that is what sealed means.  that being said, there are a couple of things you could do. you could make a wrapper class, you could create your own `scrollViewer` class, and/or you can make extension methods to add the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the beauty of WPF/Silverlight is that you often don't have to inherit from a control in order to change the way it looks or behaves. These days, a `Behavior<T>` is probably the best way to add some functionality to an existing control. Change the template if you just want it to look different.

If you let us know exactly what you want to change about a scrollviewer, I can add more detail about how to achieve this without inheritance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740136/sl-4-monitor-properties-of-scrollviewer  Can we use a Behavior to override the method on ScrollViewer that brings the RTB into view?